Difference between merge and converge in path/road/lane-related contexts?
Cambridge Dictionary and Merriam Webster Dictionary use converge and merge in very similar ways.
Cambridge uses the verb converge the following way in path/road/lane-related contexts.

converge at:
The paths all converge at the main gate of the park.


converge into:
Due to roadworks, three lanes of traffic have to converge into two
lanes.

And Merriam Learners' Dictionary uses merge and converge like this:

The two lanes merge into one.


The paths converge.

Are these two verbs synonymous in these contexts?  Since English is an overly complicated language when it comes to synonyms, I highly doubt that and this is why  I am reaching out to you.
Are they synonymous or not? If not, can you please explain the difference?
This sentence is from me:

In one hundred feet, the two paths converge into one at a signpost.


I'm not American, but I would say that paths converge when they meet at a certain point and merge when they join to become one. (Obviously, sometimes both of those things happen at the same time.)

I see but I still don't understand the difference:-/ I am sorry:-/ I am slow on the uptake today :-/ So if paths converge, they meet and then stop at the point of convergence and when they merge, they continue moving in a direction as one path?

Yes! The paths that converge at the park gate end there because the gate probably leads out onto the street.

I am so sorry about keeping picking your brain but I am so tired today and my brain just refuses to work properly, making it difficult for me to process information.                    So if the paths converge or at the gate, they stop there and don't continue behind the gate right because there is only grass there? Is my assumption correct? Or could you perhaps show me a picture of merging and converging respectively? I think that would help a lot.

Maybe you're confused because you're thinking of paths from outside the park converging at the gate. I interpreted the sentence as footpaths inside the park all leading to the gate out onto the street.

I Googled images of converging paths - a lot of them could also be described as merging. As I said, sometimes both things happen at the same time. The two terms are not mutually exclusive.

Thank you but what I still don't understand is this: Does ''merge'' imply that once two or more paths/lanes/roads have merged, they continue beyond the point where they merged as one path/lane/road whereas ''converge'' implies that once the paths/lanes/roads have met, they stop at the point of convergence and don't continue?

No. That's what I meant by both happening at the same time, and my comment about the images. Roads can converge at a point (like the famous Place Charles de Gaulle in Paris) or they can converge in a Y-shape and merge into one.

Okay... So converge puts the emphasis is on moving closer and merge puts the emphasis on becoming one thing?

More or less. Converge puts the emphasis on meeting, whether or not the paths continue as one.

What about merge?

I didn't bother to mention that because what you said is correct!

merge and converge each have a meaning that is the same in all varieties of English. There is certainly no difference with Canadian English. You are not looking at where there is actually big differences. I already gave you one: The law. King's Counsel, for example: https://www.thecanadianencyclopedia.ca/en/article/queens-counsel

I still don't understand the difference

In the US, "merge" can refer to the way traffic moves onto a road from another road by way of  a curved access, rather than by making a turn at an intersection. The curve is gradual and gives the entering traffic a chance to drive almost parallel to the road and then move into a lane when the opportunity presents itself.
Another sense is when one lane ends and traffic must move over into  an adjacent lane of traffic.
Two roads can converge (at an angle /  \ ) into a larger single road, two 2-lane roads, for example, becoming either a single 4-lane road or perhaps a single 3-lane road, one of the lanes disappearing, which requires some "jockeying".
When speaking of converging footpaths, they can end at a destination building, for example, or continue on as a single path.

Thanks, I know that merge means that in traffic-related contexts but I still don't understand the difference. Can you please focus on the examples above?

Sorry, the examples are just phrases, not detailed descriptions. There's nothing to focus on. You should try to focus on what I've written rather than ask me focus on a few fragmented sentences out of a dictionary. If you can't focus, stay off the roads.

But what additional information do you need then´?

@K945 What don't you understand?

I find it very confusing that the definitions for both verbs are very similar, making it hard for me to distinguish between them.

Are you trying to distinguish between them in a particular context, like road traffic and pedestrian traffic, or datasets, or just generally?

I have already given the context above. Roads and paths.

Well, then, I've already given you an answer. What in particular are you still in the dark about?

But you talked about merging lanes and that's not what I meant.

The paths merge/converge in 100 feet.  The three lanes merge/converge into one lane downtown.

Footpaths converge.  They meet, coming from different directions, and continue as a single path, or they end, if they converge at a destination like a building.  The traffic in the lanes of a highway must merge  when the lanes converge into a single lane.

But I have seen merge used with paths and roads. I am not talking about the traffic merging. Is my English really this bad? Is it really this hard to understand what I am asking?

It's not that your English is bad it's that you are not stating anything. Footpaths don't merge.

“Is it really this hard to understand what I am asking?” Yes, it is that hard. Precisely where are the existing responses failing you?

(Don’t repeat yourself, but instead elaborate.j

Ok here is an example with merge from Merriam Webster's learning or  Britannica's learning dictionary where merge is used in the exact same way that I am interested in.''Three lanes of traffic merge into one''.   This example isn't about one car pulling into another lane. It's about the three lanes becoming one lane and converge is used in a very similar way and I find this confusing. The examples are from Cambridge Dictionary:  ''The paths all converge at the main gate of the park.''
'' Due to roadworks, three lanes of traffic have to converge into two.''

When lanes converge, they gradually disappear because if they where to abruptl disappear, speeding cars would crash into each other.  Footpaths don't have that problem and they can simply intersect at an angle and continue as a single path.

It says "lanes of traffic".  It is referring to a column of vehicles, not the roadway.   Also, you can find all kinds of sloppy use of languagei in the world.  The highway lanes converge; the traffic merges.

I still don't understand.

Do you understand that "highway lane" and "lane of traffic" refer to different things?

I know it's lanes of traffic but I am not talking about the cars. Also, why would they disappear when converging? Please someone explain it in such a way in which I can understand. I just want to know the difference. You already know the context and gave you a bunch of sentences.

@K945 I asked you a direct question. Answer it or this is at an end.

I understand that. But can you please tell me the difference? I am talking about the lanes, in other words, the sections or the parts that a road is made up of.

@K945 I insisted that you answer the question because I believe it contains the source of your confusion.  The lanes of the highway converge.  The traffic moving in those lanes must merge when the highway's lanes converge. "lanes of traffic" refers to vehicle traffic moving in lanes.

The merging stuff in this context has been known to me for a long time. But the lanes can merge too according to the dictionaries. And since converge and merge are used in the same contexts and sentences, I cannot distinguish between them.

I guess you'll just have to stay off the roads for all of our sakes.
